# Haskell procedure

Tags: haskell

```
module Algorithm where

import System.Random
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List

type Atom = String
type Literal = (Bool,Atom)
type Clause = [Literal]
type Formula = [Clause]
type Model = [(Atom, Bool)]
type Node = (Formula, ([Atom], Model))

-- This function  takess a Clause and return the set of Atoms of that Clause.
atomsClause :: Clause -> [Atom]


-- This function  takes a Formula returns the set of Atoms of a Formula
atoms :: Formula -> [Atom]


-- This function returns True if the given Literal can be found within
-- the Clause.
isLiteral :: Literal -> Clause -> Bool


-- this function takes a Model and an Atom and flip the truthvalue of
-- the atom in the model
flipSymbol :: Model -> Atom -> Model -- is this ok?

Additional functions :
remove :: (Eq a) )a ->[a] ->[a] 
-This function removes an item from a list.

 neg :: Literal->Literal
-This function flips a literal (ie. from P to :P and from :P to P).
falseClause :: Model -> Clause -> Bool 
-This function takes a Model and a Clause and returns True
if the clause is unsatisfied by the model or False otherwise.
falseClauses :: Formula -> Model -> [Clause]
-This function takes a Formula and a Model and returns the list of clauses of the  formula that are not satisfied.
 assignModel :: Model -> Formula -> Formula 
 -This function applies the assign function for all the assignments of a given model.
 checkFormula :: Formula -> Maybe Bool This function checks whether a formula can be  decided to be satisfiable or unsatisfiable based on the effects of the assign function.
 satisfies :: Model -> Formula -. Bool This function checks whether a model satisfies a formula. This is done with the combination of the assignModel and checkFormula functions.
```

Comment: I didn't upload the code for the funtion I wrote because of the space...I ca do so If you require.

Comment: @TKFALS: Put i t into some pastebin and post a link. You may edit your question to add the link.  Thank you for using formatting.

Comment: This is a very, very long question. (tl;dr)

Comment: @Dan:I know there are the last 5 from a long set of ex.

Comment: @FUZxxL,thanks for the reply,I didn.t format in the past because....well I was new to stack ovr and I wasn't paying attention.For the first one I was thinking on taking out each clause an somehow searching for the same literals then comparing their values to establish a conclusion

Comment: To your function `node`: Wouldn't be the type `Node -> (Node,Node)` better, as you akways have exactly two elements?

Comment: @FUZxxl...I posted the ling with the codes

Comment: No,it is an ex...it has to stay like that.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: @TKFALS: To your whole questions: OIn order to give you a good answer, it would be interesting, how you estimate your level of haskell knowledge.

Comment: @mokus..those are the ramaining 5 function that I'm working on...the description below them I wrote it to explain it how they should behave

Comment: @TKFALS tl;dr as well. Don't try and cram umpteen questions into a single one. If these are 5 exercises, they should be 5 SO questions. Feel free to provide links to the preceding questions in the follow-ups. A more descriptive name than "Haskell procedure" will also help you attract persons to answer your questions. Also, what does DPLL stand for? We are not in your class, remember!

Comment: @Jeremy W. Sherman---Davis-Putnam-Logemann-Loveland ,they are the last 5 functions ,and they are connected with this part,the DPLL procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One place to get you started: look at

```
 removeTautologies :: Formula -> Formula
```

Now suppose we can write an function

```
 isTautology :: Clause -> Bool
```

Then we may have a chance of using that function to *filter* general formulae. So I would attempt to ignore everything but the function `isTautology`. Essentially the question here is: *What is a tautology* and *how do we detect it?* Some of the ideas posted by Edward Z. Yang should definitely help you here in understanding what is going on. In this case, we could look at the clause `[(True,"A"), (True,"B"), (False,"A")]` and try to feed it to `isTautology` for testing it. Likewise with the other clause Edward posted, `[(True,"B"), (True,"C"), (True,"A")]`.

The trick in general is to figure out how to break up the functions into smaller constituents which are easily written and then afterwards glue these individual pieces together with code to solve the final problem. We are decomposing `removeTautologies` which works on general formulae into a helper `isTautology` which can work on clauses in the formula, and then we seek to define `removeTautologies` in terms of it via some *filtering* glue code.

I hope this helps you start on your problem. It may seem to be quite irrelevant but do take note that more advanced variants of this is used in Model Checking algorithms which verify that your CPU is correct, that protocols behave and recently is has also been used in automatic refactoring, see http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/ for a use. So this problem is a good way to learn some serious applicability in the real world!

---

I'll edit it here to help you rather than replying in the comment section. You wrote:

```
rt ((x, x') : (y, y') : rest) | x' == y' = rt rest
                              | otherwise = (x, x') : rt ((y, y') : rest)
```

There are a couple of problems with this approach as you mention. First, the game is that your `rt` function is working on clauses. If the given clause is a tautology it should be removed, so it would be better to call it `isTautology` with the type I mention above, or perhaps simply:

```
isRemovableClause :: Clause -> Bool
```

The path you have taken requires you to sort the list in the clause lexicographically and then consider what to do in the case you have `[P, P, not P, Q]` for instance. Another approach is to establish a search. Suppose we have

```
isRemovableClause ((tv, name) : rest) = ...
```

Notice that if the value `(not tv, name)` is present in `rest` this clause must be a tautology. Otherwise, we can throw away `(tv, name)` and look for a tautology in `rest`.

Moving the focus to `removeTautologies`, it is clear that the function can be written using `isRemovableClause`: A formula is a list of clauses, so we can simply walk through the clause-list and remove all those for which `isRemovableClause` returns true. The bold solver will use `List.filter`, a higher order function, to achieve this.

Comment: rt ((x, x'):(y, y'):rest)
    | x' == y' = rt rest
    | otherwise = (x, x') : rt ((y, y') : rest)
but I'm not satisfied because the check is concesecutive...if ro example I have as
literals (P,Q,-P) P will never compare with -P

Comment: Threw you a prod in the right direction and edited my answer.

Comment: @ I GIVE CRAP ANSWERS(your name is an irony), thank you,I'm going to post my progress, is it ok if we continue to stay in touch?

Comment: I'm going to apply your advice to the construction of the function but first let me share with you another ideea that I had before I saw your comment(please bear in mind that I have 2 weeks of haskell so any absurd mistakes that I make are....justified),now....removeTautology=map rt.map head.group.sort.....map head.group.sort is suppose to sort the list and remove duplicates.

Comment: killing duplicates and sorting is definitely a viable solution also.

Comment: ok now  with that in mind I can use a similair tactic to "conquer" the definition for the next function..pureLiteralDeletion=map ld.map head.group.sort.concat                     where lD ((x, x') : (y, y') : rest) | x' == y' && x/=y = lD rest
                              | otherwise = (x, x') : lD ((y, y') : rest)

Comment: @ I GIVE CRAP ANSWERS, although I'm not content with the definition of ld....but there again I can just build a function to filter what I don't need.

Comment: I'd advise you to split up your gigantic 5 questions (or so) and do them one at a time. That way it is easier for others to chime in with their ideas for solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This question is too broad: it might be marginally OK if you focused on one particular function that you needed help on, but really, in order for us to effectively, you need to give us more than just the specification of what the code should to: with only that, this is just a "Do my homework for me" problem.

That being said, I recommend taking the examples you posted in your descriptions and converting them to your representation (I assume you're using CNF?) Then you'll have something along the lines of

```
(A v B v -A) ^ (B v C v A)
```

becomes

```
[[(True,"A"), (True,"B"), (False,"A")],
 [(True,"B"), (True,"C"), (True,"A")]]
```

and then think about what the resulting data type looks like, and how you might get there from a strictly computational perspective. Don't worry about performance.

Comment: rt ((x, x'):(y, y'):rest)
    | x' == y' = rt rest
    | otherwise = (x, x') : rt ((y, y') : rest)
but I'm not satisfied because the check is concesecutive...if ro example I have as
literals (P,Q,-P) P will never compare with -P